# stringWithFormat Bad Access error

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, stringwithformat

Can anyone explain why this code works perfectly:

```
int thumbnailPrefix = trunc([newGraph.dateCreated timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);

newGraph.thumbnailImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@",thumbnailPrefix,@"png"];
```

But this code causes a Bad Access error?

```
newGraph.thumbnailImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@",trunc([newGraph.dateCreated timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]),@"png"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trunc` returns a `double`, not an `int`.

```
double trunc(double x);
```

So in the first code block you are converting it to an `int`, and correctly using the `%d` format specifier.

In the second, it should be an `%f`, or have `(int)` in front of it.

```
newGraph.thumbnailImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)trunc([newGraph.dateCreated timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]),@"png"];
```

Comment: Or, more specifically, %d expects a 32 bit argument and trunk returns a 64 bit argument. Thus, the %@ is trying to treat the second half of the return value of trunc() as an id and **Boom**.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I thought trunc returned an integer.  Thanks for clarifying guys.  This site gives me more info than all my objective C books combined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typecasting the return from trunk() like....

```
newGraph.thumbnailImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)trunc([newGraph.dateCreated timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]),@"png"];
```

It's a shot in the dark, but I expect NSString doesn't know the return type for the function trunc.